# Можно ли изменить версию локальной БД?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

Проблема в следующем: у меня есть 2 сервера к которым я смог подключиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База работает только на сервере "SC0304" (имя компа), но работает не корректно. На сервере "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" не работает вообще. Для корректной работы мне нужно на сервере "SC0304" поставить сервер более высокой версии. Я думал это решиться установкой SQl Server более новой версии. Однако обновилась версия сервера "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB".
Сейчас у меня работаю следующие серверы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, можно ли как-то изменить версию сервера "SC0304" ??

И как подключиться к серверy "MSSQLSERVERV12" (это сервер который я установил)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для обновления версии Вам при инсталации нужно было вместо `New SQL
   Server stand-alone installation` выбрать `Upgrade from SQL Server
   2005, SQL Server 2008...`.
2. Запустите SQL Management Studio и выполните запрос `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`. Он вернет вам название сервера.

Comment: спасибо! коротко и ясно!

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос, можно ли как-то изменить версию сервера "SC0304" ??
>
> И как подключиться к серверy "MSSQLSERVERV12" (это сервер который я установил)?

1) Как я понял изменить версию нельзя

2) Для того чтобы подключиться к требуемому серверу, после имени компьютера через слэш дописываем нужный сервер `SC0304\MSSQLSERVERV12`

Comment: Как и упоминалось выше вам необходимо обновить сервер SC0304 с помощью оснастки Upgrade from sql server..  При обновлении на одном из шагов укажите инстанс который обновляете MSSqlServer.